# C# Adding data into, or removing data from, a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

I am hoping that by asking this question I find a far more effiecient method of doing what it is that I am trying to do.

To start, I have a function whose parameters look as follows:

```
private void exampleVoid(string filePath, params string[] sourceFile) {

// Code ...

}
```

#### **Notice: I am passing the 'sourceFile' parameters into a CodeDom method. This method throws an error if any of the parameters are null.**

My call to `exampleVoid` looks as follows:

```
exampleVoid(@"C:\test.txt",
"Some Data",
"Some More Data",
"Even more data");
```

Under certain cercumstances, the second string in the array (labled "Some More Data") may have to be removed and *not* passsed to the `exampleVoid()` method. So, is there some way of removing this string from the array alltogether? Keep in mind that nulling the string out will not work as an exception will be thrown.

Thank you for reading, as well as any further help.

Evan

Comment: How do you know what index that has to be removed? And where should it be removed? Before or after it has reached exampleVoid?

Comment: I'll need the 2nd index to be removed. Say I declare a boolean (b_removeArrayIndex), if this boolean is true, I would like the array to be removed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot remove the string from the array. Creating a new array that includes all other items except the one you want to include is your only option. The code is easy enough:

```
// Filters out the second item (zero-based index 1)
sourceFile = sourceFile.Where((s, i) => i != 1).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. I'm definitely going to be looking into some documentation of this to figure out exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question...
Having said that, you could try this:

```
string[] sourceFile;
if(condition)
    sourceFile = new []{"Some Data","Even more data"};
else
    sourceFile = new []{"Some Data","Some More Data","Even more data"};

exampleVoid(@"C:\test.txt", sourceFile);
```